# Why mutual information gives me negative results

Tags: r, mutual-information

I have the following table:

```
> dput(observed)
structure(list(yes = c(1427L, 165L, 104L), no = c(6212L, 1594L, 
693L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

i.e.

```
> observed
   yes   no
1 1427 6212
2  165 1594
3  104  693
```

I would like to estimate the mutual information between $X$ (rows of the table) and $Y$ (columns of the table). Here $O$ is the entry of previous table and $\text{sum}(O)$  is the sum of al the entries:
$$    I(X ; Y)=\sum_{y \in\{1,2\}} \sum_{x \in\{1,3\}} \frac{O_{x y}}{\text{sum}(O)} \ln \left(\frac{O_{x y}}{(O_{x 1}+O_{x2}) (O_{1y}+O_{2y}+O_{3y})}\right)$$
So I wrote the code:

```
I<-vector()
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    arg <- observed[j,i]/(sum(observed[j,])*sum(observed[,i]))
    S <- observed[j,i]/sum(observed)*log2(arg)
    I = c(I,S)
  }
}
I
sum(I)
```

but it gives me the result: $-13.30799$. (MI should be non-negative!) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did this formula come from?  It doesn't quite agree with the standard definitions, such as on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#In_terms_of_PMFs_for_discrete_distributions).  Your formula is guaranteed never to yield a positive number, because the arguments of the logarithm never exceed $1.$

Comment: It comes from a book by Duboue: "The Art of Feature Engineering Essentials for Machine Learning", chapter 4.1.1.

Comment: You can report errors at http://artoffeatureengineering.com/errata.html.